# Do Pentecostals disagree with women preaching?

Tags: women, pentecostalism, authority, female-clergy

On whether or not women can be preachers, know several who disagree: Voddie Bauchman, John MacArthur, Norman Geisler, John Pipper, Albert Mohler, Yago Martins (from "Dois Dedos de Teologia"), etc.

Considering their background are Calvinist, Baptist and / or Presbyterian, is it perhaps one of the things that distinguishes them from Pentecostals? Or are there Pentecostals too that disagree with it?

Comment: There's lots of diversity within Pentecostalism. I'm sure the answer will be that some do and some don't.

Comment: I thought so that at first but didn't find any from the known names @curiousdannii.

Comment: I come from a denomination which is connected to the Pentecostal "Movement" - not a denomination. I think you will find your question is better phrased (1) around Pentecostal views of women in ministry since 'preaching' is often permitted is non-egalitarian congregations, and (2) without reference to non-Pentecostals since this seems to confuse the issues. Most Calvinist/Baptist/Presbyterian congregations and teachers are explicitly complementarian, but this is not a defining characteristic. Likewise, Pentecostals originate from egalitarian roots, but are defined by their belief in the Spirit.

Comment: Time Square Church though a non denominational church draws on pentecostal traditions, they have female preachers that are not limited to female only audiences or underage audiences. I’ve asked them to explain their position Biblically hoping I could learn something but they sent me a standardized email that didn’t have Biblical backing. It was an argument from human reason which was disappointing. But outside the US, UK and other western liberal countries pentecostal churches adhere to traditional no female preachers. This is changing with fringe movements mimicking western churches